# multiple arguments in a function to run through arrary_filter

Tags: php

How can i run multiple arguments through `array_filter`? Here is my function with the multiple arguments and the `array_filter` code

```
function is_txt($file, $user) {
return preg_match('/backup-[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+_[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}_'.$user.'.tar.gz/', $file) > 0;
}

....

$list = ftp_nlist($conn_id, $ftp_dir);
$filtered = array_filter($list, 'is_txt');
if(count($filtered)){
foreach( $filtered as $name => $file){

echo $file; 
echo "<br>";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use anonymous function:

```
$filtered = array_filter($list, function($file) use ($user) {
  return is_txt($file, $user);
});
```

*※PHP version need to >= 5.3*